# Securing Tomcat Using SSL Behind an Apache2 Virtual Host

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, apache2, tomcat7

I have a tomcat server running behind apache virtual hosts (so I can use multiple domains on the same server). All the apache does is take the host name and forward the request to the proper tomcat server, which handles everything thereafter.

I am looking to setup SSL on one of the domains and I understand the process of how to do so but I am confused on whether I should be allowing tomcat to handle all SSL or apache.

What is the difference? Any downsides to allowing tomcat to handle the ssl? If I let apache handle the ssl will I still get green bar, padlock etc when I access the tomcat app? I'm a little confused about the whole situation.

I use a proxy to handle apache2 forwarding to the proper tomcat app. If I setup the proxy like so:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
    ServerName host.domain.org

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.key

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / https://localhost:8443/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8443/
</VirtualHost>
```

Will I need to use https and port 8443? Doing it this way won't I also have to setup SSL on tomcat? Or can I use the following in the connector of tomcat's server.xml

```
secure = false
scheme = https
proxyName = www.mydomain.com
proxyPort = 443
```

And not worry about connecting tomcat to the ssl keys? Is this the proper way to secure a tomcat app using SSL through apache2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you state in the config you give, you'd have two distinct https connections per request. Number one from any client to your apache. Apache would decrypt the request and - in order to forward it - negotiate an SSL connection with tomcat. You'd have to set up https on both machines this way.

You can just forward with http to tomcat (typically port 8080). However, it might be that tomcat does not see that you're using https this way (you'd have to try it out). If you use ajp, e.g. mod_jk or mod_proxy_ajp, instead of http between apache and tomcat, tomcat would definitely also see the https connection.

What you should do depends on the distance between Apache and tomcat - and on your level of trust on the network between the two. I'd say it's typically no problem to run this connection unencrypted, but your mileage may vary.

What do you gain from handling https on apache? Well, I'd assume Apache might scale a bit better on session negotiation and encryption - at least it offloads the crypto-stuff onto a different server, allowing tomcat to do what it does best (serving applications) and let Apache handle all the weird crypto stuff.

I like this configuration - typically you can also fix some issues quickly with mod_rewrite, load balancing etc., so that an extra apache allows you to be a lot more flexible than "just" a tomcat.

Comment: Have you encountered any problems with this configuration. I am running the same configuration but I am having problems with the web apps that keep redirecting to the http(80) port. Also, some of the content being served is not in http and I wonder if its because of tomcat not being aware that it is being run in SSL?